# using float.Parse() vs casting to get a value from double

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

I wasn't able to find a question that directly answers this question, I came across this line of code in a project at work (I added the comment)

```
// act.score is a double
float score = float.Parse(act.score.ToString());
```

**Is there a greater loss of precision in converting double -> string-> float vs double -> float?**

The original engineer no longer works here, but I know he comes from a python background, so maybe he wasn't aware of the loss of precision? Or would there be a reason to convert to string first, and then to float?

in case I sound confusing, for reference, this is what I would have done:

```
float score = (float)act.score;
```

Comment: Well converting a double to a string would typically give 15 digits of precision. String to float gives 7 digits of precision. So there isn't a greater loss of precision. I'm guessing the engineer wasn't too bothered about it.

Comment: converting to string is less accurate, if not less its not more precise either

Comment: Also the cast should be faster, because it don't need to allocate an string.

Comment: Check out link for great answer on FP and why he did the strings most likely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272842/how-to-cast-float-to-double-without-extra-digits-added

Comment: And another good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986980/convert-float-to-double-loses-precision-but-not-via-tostring

Comment: @JasonW that first one is a great read, thanks

Comment: @Vanna, I did not test this directly, this is sensitive code I am not trying to touch, I just came across this line and wasn't sure about it

Comment: The two above links are for converting `float -> double` and not `double -> float` as in the OP

Comment: With `double d = 402441647.99999994`, the two methods yield different answers: casting yields `402441632` while `float.Parse(d.ToString())` yields `402441664`
[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZCJyyp)